# Is not the substitution method supposed to reduce the computation cost?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, gurobi, convex-optimization, cvxpy

Is the substitution method expected to **reduce** the computation cost? We know it will reduce the number of variables and constraints.

I mean by substitution method is to eliminate the **equality** constraints when possible.

A simple illustrative example might be:

```
minimize z
Subject to:
z=x-2
0<x<1
```

This can be reduced to:

```
minimize x-2
Subject to:
0<x<1
```

When I use the substitution on a large problem, the computation time decreases if I use gurobipy but increases if I use CVXPY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a long equality constraint $x=\sum_j a_j y_j$ and $x$ appears multiple times in your model, performing the substitution can greatly increase the number of nonzero coefficients in the constraint matrix, and that typically hurts the performance.

Comment: Agree with that as it reduces variables but Dr @RobPratt won't it increase the rows to process?

Comment: Perhaps it depends upon solver whether they are using dynamic column generation or row generation. That may explain perf diff between gurobipy and cvxpy

Comment: @Sutanu yes there is a trade-off., but having one “extra” variable and constraint to significantly reduce density of several other constraints is usually a good thing.